# How to find the second vertex of a line segment from a given angle and length

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If you have the (h,k) coordinates of a point, how to you calculate the coordinates of the other endpoint of a line segment if you have the angle $\alpha$ and length$L$?

Comment: $(x,y)\pm r\cdot(\cos \theta,\sin\theta)$ is a more straightforward formula

Comment: @user3063750 $ x= h+L \cos \alpha , y= k+ L \sin \alpha$

Comment: @ user3063750 Sorry, please roll back if required. I put in standard symbols for convenience

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta$ be our angle, $r$ our length, and $(x',y')$ our end point.

$$r = \sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2}$$
$$\tan{\theta} = \frac{y'-y}{x'-x}$$

Then it is just a matter of solving these two equations for $x'$ and $y'$

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: If you need to know how this was done, draw a triangle with vertices $(x,y)$, $(x',y')$ and $(x',y)$. This is right angled, and $r$ is the length of the hypotenuse. $\theta$ is interior angle of the triangle at $(x,y)$, then use standard trig identities.

Answer (score 0):

comment

Rough sketch of the above

[image]